# Program architecture, Fragments/Activitys

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Firstly let me apologise for the terrible flow diagram I attempted to produce,

I am creating my first android app, and trying to build it correctly rather than just throwing it together and making it work.

and although everything works how Id like it to so far, I don't feel comfortable with the way I am using activity's and fragments,
I feel that my current structure is causing things to be considerably more difficult.

I have started to struggle when I wanted to have a logout button on the activity bar throughout the app (once logged in)
I was wanting this to close the current fragment and navigate me back to the login screen. This along with the fact most of my code is in main activity is where it stops making sense and gives me reason to believe there s a deeper routed issue with how I am doing things.

Home fragment is a menu
[image: diagram]

Edit!!

This is how it currently looks, I'm now wondering if I should remove the homeFragment, and just load that data direct to MainActivity,
At the minute its only a simple menu, but it will almost certainly contain more things in the future, (however I imagine Ill only need the one fragment)
But it would be the first instance where I have put content into an activity rather than into a fragment held by an activity, so should I continue this way if only for continuity.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps put a LoginActivity at the start before the MainActivity. Your app will always start there, but if the user is already logged in, it  starts Main Activity and immediately calls `finish()`. Then whenever the user presses the logout button, you start the LoginActivity again. Edit - The LoginActivity would 'own' the Register and Login Fragment

Comment: Exactly as I've done with the activity activity, my brain has been overloaded this week and isn't running at optimum haha, I had tried to piece that solution together, and kept running into brick walls, brain ram issue, so obvious now you have mentioned it, I will see where that gets me :)#

Comment: I know the feeling... Yes, I suppose, but in that case, you won't need HomeFragment? Unless it does something I can't think of, you'd jump straight to FragmentPlayGame?

Comment: Home fragment is a menu that is held inside a layout in Home Activity,
Does that make sense or am I going wrong there as well  ?
Should I just do away with the fragment and put it inside the activity?
That sounds right, Then when I call Activity Activity my Home activity would be in the back stack?
And ActivityActivity Could load the correct fragment?

Apologies, I want to have this first project as perfect as possible, as this will be my reference point in future projects :D

Comment: I don't see HomeActivity on your diagram, so I'm not certain I'm afraid. It's difficult to generalise, but you should have one Activity that deals with any login procedures and hosts the Fragments associated with that. That should then finish and start your main application Activity - depending of the complexity, that single Activity could host all of the game Fragments. There are a lot of ActivtyActivity naming conventions, so it gets a little confusing. You certainly seem to be on the right track though, the fact that you asked this question shows that.

Comment: Apologies HomeActivity = MainActivity
I have changed it up and just debugging as I broke something, but I shall create a new flow diagram to update my original post

Comment: Looks much better. I would suggest keeping your content in Fragments - perhaps do away completely with MainActivity and have HomeFragment as the first view in ActivityActivity with the other content (that was in the Activity) in HomeParentFragment